# Convert data to duration

Tags: regex, google-sheets, time, sum, duration

I need to convert the info in the Raw Data Column to the displayed info in column I.

Is there any formula that can accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: Google Apps Script will be your best bet, I suppose.

Comment: May you help me with the script?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nzBCWYp4_9QpZLSx0PvDDnBd2hoHNJpKoTq09Jiwaq0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Not duly shared, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A10="";;TEXT((
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A10; "(\d+)h")*3600)+
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A10; "(\d+)m")*60)+
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A10; "(\d+)s")))/86400; "[hh]:mm:ss")))
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly!!! May you kindly explain how this formula works?

Comment: @mau sure, we extract hours and multiply it by 60 and again by 60 (coz 1h=60m and 1m=60s) then we extract minutes and multiply it only by 60 and next we extract seconds. this way we converted hours and minutes into seconds so we just sum all seconds and divide by 86400 (coz 1day=86400s) and we use TEXT to format it to hh:mm:ss. to work with duration we enclose hh into [hh] so now even 500 minutes can be converted into 8h 20m

Comment: What about the reg expression?

Comment: @mau `"(\d+)h"` means "get any/all numbers before h"

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much, just one more question. I'm trying to get now the average of that range, but I've got the #DIV/0 error. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Seems like is for the text formula, can we convert it to numbers?

Comment: Seems like this fixes the issue =ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D4:D="",,TEXT((
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(D4:D, "(\d+)h")*3600)+
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(D4:D, "(\d+)m")*60)+
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(D4:D, "(\d+)s")))/86400, "[hh]:mm:ss")))))

Comment: @mau https://i.stack.imgur.com/tO5ul.png